# When to use JoranConfigurator?

Tags: logback

Can someone explain to me when should we use JoranConfigurtor?
I have logback.xml existing in a directory. I wonder what's happening in this piece of code?

Doesn't `LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();` initializes the context? So what is Joran is doing?

```
 private static void configureLoggerContext(String logbackConfigFileUrl) {
    File file = new File(logbackConfigFileUrl);
    LoggerListener loggerListener = new LoggerListener();
    LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
    loggerContext.reset();
    loggerContext.addListener(loggerListener);
    JoranConfigurator configurator = new JoranConfigurator();
    configurator.setContext(loggerContext);
    try {
        configurator.doConfigure(file);
    } catch (JoranException je) {
        throw new RuntimeException(je.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Joran`a is just a configuration library that `Logback` relies on.
https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#joranDirectly

Comment: I have added a <fileHeader> tag in my logback.xml and by running the code above my file header is printed twice. once when it's initialized and second when it's reconfigured with joran.

Comment: Well that i obvious as logback is doing the same thing what you are doing here under the hood.Logback.xml is picked automaticly. Rename it so it will not be autodetected

Answer (score 1):

You use `JoranConfigurator` to configure your logging when your application needs explicit configuration rather than just using something like `web.xml` on a servlet environment (which will use the configurator behind the scenes).

For example, if you create a simple desktop application and you would want to config using a local `logback.xml` file, you would load it using the configurator

```
JoranConfigurator configurator = new JoranConfigurator();
        configurator.setContext(context);
        configurator.doConfigure(new File("path/to/logback.xml"));
```

The logger context is just the context of Logback which includes the implementation of the logback components, it will allow you to create Loggers for your classes. when `.doConfigure` is called, the context will be configured according to what's inside the `logback.xml`.

From the LoggerContext doc:

> LoggerContext implements the ILoggerFactory acting as the manufacturing source of Logger instances.